# Python Classes (Basic)

Tags: python, oop, class

Working code is here: http://codepad.org/L0OkeHlk

```
from sys import exit

class Map(object):

    def __init__(self, start):
        self.start = start

    def play(self):
        next = self.start

        while True:
            print "\n---------"
            room = getattr(self,next)
            next = room()

    def death(self):
        exit(1)

    def redroom(self):
        prompt = raw_input("> ")
        if "white" in prompt:
            return "whiteroom"
        elif "blue" in prompt:
            return "blueroom"
        else:
            print "DOES NOT COMPUTE (RED ROOM)"
            return 'death'

    def whiteroom(self):
        prompt = raw_input("> ")
        if "red" in prompt:
            return "redroom"
        elif "blue" in prompt:
            return "blueroom"
        else:
            print "DOES NOT COMPUTE (WHITE ROOM)"
            return 'death'

    def blueroom(self):
        prompt = raw_input("> ")
        if "white" in prompt:
            return "whiteroom"
        elif "red" in prompt:
            return "redroom"
        else:
            print "DOES NOT COMPUTE (BLUE ROOM)"
            return 'death'

class Engine(object):
    pass

x = Map("redroom")
x.play()
```

The above works.  But only because I'm doing everything in one class.  I want to take the play and death functions and put them in a class of their own.

My problem comes from two places.  How do I get the Engine class to call the functions in the map class to make the game work?  How do I know what to initialize in the Map/Engine class?  I get that I'm supposed to initialize something but I have no idea how to come up with it.  What should be my first thought when deciding what to initialize?

Non-functioning code (my best attempt): http://codepad.org/ELlaHQiB

```
from sys import exit

class Map(object):

    def redroom(self):
        prompt = raw_input("> ")
        if "white" in prompt:
            return "whiteroom"
        elif "blue" in prompt:
            return "blueroom"
        else:
            print "DOES NOT COMPUTE (RED ROOM)"
            return 'death'

    def whiteroom(self):
        prompt = raw_input("> ")
        if "red" in prompt:
            return "redroom"
        elif "blue" in prompt:
            return "blueroom"
        else:
            print "DOES NOT COMPUTE (WHITE ROOM)"
            return 'death'

    def blueroom(self):
        prompt = raw_input("> ")
        if "white" in prompt:
            return "whiteroom"
        elif "red" in prompt:
            return "redroom"
        else:
            print "DOES NOT COMPUTE (BLUE ROOM)"
            return 'death'

class Engine(object):
    def __init__(self, start):
        self.start = start

    def play(self):
        next = self.start

        while True:
            print "\n---------"
            room = getattr(self,next)
            next = room()

    def death(self):
        exit(1)

x = Engine("redroom")
x.play()
```

Also, I'm unsure of the play function.  It works but only because I got it from the tutorial I was reading.  What is the purpose of the next variable becoming self.start and then becoming room() in the while loop?

Comment: I think you can try create a class call `Room`, and either have them as subclass `redroom`, `blueroom`? The `play` function can be implemented in your `Room` class, so it is available to all of them. Finally you can put all the `Room` objects into a map.

Comment: Why do you want classes here at all? Far from wanting more, you should question whether you need any. You're not doing any data encapsulation, which is the main reason for doing classes in Python.

Comment: `getattr(self,next)` is looking for an attribute of `x` called `redroom`, and it does not have such an attribute.  It's hard to work out what you are trying to do here, but I doubt you need to use `getattr`.  It also seems odd to represent "rooms" as methods of "Map", and it is probably a good idea to avoid naming variables `next` as that is the name of an important built-in function.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm doing it because it is part of the course work for Learn Python the Hard Way

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do.

```
class Engine(object):
    def __init__(self,rooms):
        self.rooms = rooms
        self.current = 0

    def next(self):
        self.rooms[self.current]()
        self.current += 1
        if len(self.rooms) == self.current:
            self.current = 0
            # or whatever logic you want.

m = Map()
rooms = [m.redroom, m.whiteroom, m.blueroom]
e = Engines(rooms)

e.next() # should call redroom of class Map
e.next() # should call whiteroon etc
```